# Unity3D: How to change Transform's (GameObject's) color?

Tags: unity-game-engine, unity3d-gui

In old versions of Unity Component's renderer had material, now UnityEngine.Renderer has material, but Component.renderer doesn't have.
How can I change the color of my object?

```
private Transform myTransform;

...

private void changeColor()
{
    myTransform.renderer.**material**.color = Color.red;
    // renderer doesn't have *material*
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By this [thread](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/909215/unity-5-gameobjectrenderermaterial.html), try

```
GetComponent<Renderer>().material.color = Color.black;
```

Comment: then maybe try calling `myTransform.GetComponent<Renderer>().material.color = Color.black;`

Comment: It warked. But this element doesn't have Renderer, it has MeshRenderer. So, why it warked?

Comment: @GuRAm it also has the Renderer component, it just has a different access way towards it.